# My panel bar is gone

Tags: wingpanel

Hello My panel bat is gone how do I fix this. I been looking everywhere. I tired looking on Google nothing **works**

Answer (score 0):

If the panel is gone, this can usually be fixed with a reboot. You may need to issue the command from Terminal, though. Here's how:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open Terminal
2. Reboot the system:

   ```
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```

If the wing panel does not return after booting, then it has either been removed for some reason or is running into an error. Be sure to update your question with more details if a reboot does not resolve the issue.